# Like Dislike Toggle using custom template tags

Tags: python, django

I want the text inside button to toggle between like and dislike .Im trying to accomplish this using custom template tags . The like and dislike is working and model is getting updated. Just want the button to toggle between like and dislike!

I have created the template tags folder .Just want help in creating the template tag function inside post_extras.py and how to call the function inside the template

post_extras.py

```
    from django import template

    register = template.Library()


    @register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
    def isliked(context,entry):
    if entry.filter(id=context['request'].post.id).exists():
      return "Unlike"
    else:
      return "Like"
```

like_section.html

```
    {% load post_extras %}
    {{ entry.total_likes }} Like{{ entry.total_likes | pluralize }}
    <form action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" name="{{ entry.id }}" value="like" class="btn 
    btn-primary like"/>
    </form>
```

models.py

```
    class Post(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    text = models.TextField(null=False)
    created_date=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='image', blank='True')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.heading



    def getuser(self):
        return self.user.username

    def total_likes(self):
        return Like.objects.filter(post=self).count()



    class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.heading
```

ajax code:

```
   $(document).on('click','.like',function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var pks=$(this).attr('name');
   console.log('primarys : '+ pks);
   $.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url:'like/',
   data:{
   'ids': pks,
   csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
   },
   success:function (response) {
   $(e.target).parents('.like-section').html(response);
   console.log(response)
   console.log("liked");
   },
   error: function(rs,e){
        console.log(rs, e.responseText);
        console.log('ERROR');
   },
   });
   });
```

views.py

def like_post(request):

```
post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('ids'))
like=Like.objects.filter(user=request.user, post=post)
if like.exists():
    like.delete()
else:
    Like.objects.create(user=request.user, post=post)
    send_mail(
        'Post Liked',
        'Your Post "'+ post.heading + '" has been liked by '+request.user.username,
        'mohitharshan123@gmail.com',
        [post.user.email],
        fail_silently=False,
    )
context= {
      'entry': post,
     }
if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('accounts/like_section.html', context, request=request)
        return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: You call the custom tag in Django template like this: `{% isliked %}`

Comment: My function is not done right .Can you figure out how to write the function

Comment: @petr My function is not done right.Any idea how to write the function? (isliked)

Comment: You pass arguments like this: `{% isliked entry %}` Does it work now?

Comment: @petr  No .doessnt work .Please note im using another like table for managing the likes.The function i have written is wrong it seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    from django import template
    from posts.models import Like
    register = template.Library()


   @register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
   def isliked(context, post):
     try:
       obj = Like.objects.get(post=post,user=context['request'].user)
       return "Unlike"
     except Like.DoesNotExist:
    return "Like"
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, a post is `Liked` if it exists in the `Like` model.

**Solution**:

```
from django import template

# import `Like` model
from path.to.models import Like

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def isliked(post):
    if Like.objects.filter(post=post).exists():
        return "Like"
    return "Unlike"
```

You can then load it in the template: `{% load isliked %}`.
And, then use it by passing an instance of `Post` model: `{% isliked post %}`.

Comment: MultipleObjectsReturned at /home/
get() returned more than one Like -- it returned 4!..

Comment: should i do user =requerst['context']

Comment: Also if Like does not exist ,It should return "Like",else "unlike" .I think its inverted in your code ?

Comment: Thanks.I figured it out

Comment: The issue with this is that many users can like many posts.The user which has liked a post should only be able to unlike it.

Comment: Right. For that you need to take in context and from that the request which will give you the current authenticated user, which you can use to filter the `Like` objects queryset along with the `post`. If you need the working code sample, then I can edit the answer.

Comment: I thought it was about if the post is liked or not. I didnt realize that you were trying to show the user that he has liked it or not.

Comment: No need .I figured it out! Thanks

Comment: Its great that you figured it out. But, you should post whatever worked for you as an answer to help other users with the same problem.

Comment: You didnt understand what I was telling you. "Post it as an answer" !